# SauceLabs tunnel with Android emulator not working

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android, saucelabs

I am using Saucelabs for automated web tests, where is used "Sauce connect" tunnel to access our backend which is in VPN. This is working fine.
I started automated tests for android app on SauceLabs emulator where I also want to use same tunnel..
I can run the test, but problem is that android app is not able to conect to backend - tunnel works not.

I am using robot framework, this is command to open app:

```
Open Application    ${REMOTE_URL}    platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}    deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}    
app=${APP}    automationName=appium    appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE}     autoGrantPermissions=true    noReset=false    newCommandTimeout=180    
appiumVersion=1.16.0    tunnelIdentifier={TUNNEL_ID}    parentTunnel=${PARENT}
```

Tunnel is recognized in SauceLabs, but traffic is not send via it.
Tunnel is up and running fine with web page test on same account, but not used on same time
Is there any additional setup necessary ?
On web tests there is send SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY and SAUCE_USERNAME as parameteer of capabilities, I tried to add it also here but no succes.

Comment: Paste a link to the sauce job, I can look at what sauce is receiving from robot maybe there's a syntax issue.

Comment: What is the error you get? In Robot this style of having keyword arguments over multiple lines is handled with ``...`` on the beginning of each line. So your script would behave currently as if the lines are supposed to use separate keywords instead of sending it all to the ``Open Application``.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to look at the configuration which Sauce Labs received, I would guess that either:

1. @Morkkis is correct and this style of configuration isn't passing your arguments correctly
2. Your Android tests are configuring a separate proxy that's over-riding Sauce Connect
3. Your Sauce Connect tunnel is configured to only send specific traffic via the tunnel, and your mobile app's traffic doesn't match